# jquery focus on div works on ie10 but not on firefox/chrome

Tags: jquery, focus

My code basically is supposed to show the `updateLogText div` and focus on the `middle div` which is positioned below it.

here is the code:

```
$('#updateLogButton').click(function(event) {


    if ($('#updateLogText').is(':visible')){
        //hide div if content is visible
        $('#updateLogText').fadeOut();

    }else{

        $('#updateLogText').fadeIn();
        $('#middle').focus(); 
    }
        return false;

    });
```

Adding the div code for completeness:

```
<?php 
                    if ( $num_of_updates != 0){
       ?>
       <div id="showUpdates">

        <a href="#" id="updateLogButton">View Update Log: <?php echo $num_of_updates ?></a>


            <?php } ?>


            <div id="updateLogText">
                    <?php 


                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($updates_log_result)){
                        echo '<div class="commentbox">';
                        echo $row['comments'];
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="commentfooter">Posted by '.$row['user'].' @ '.$row['datestamp'].'</div>';

                        echo'<br>';
                        }   

                    ?>
                </div>
          </div>

 <div id="middle">

     <div id="custExpBox">
       <div class="titleText boxTitle"> Customer Experience </div>  
      <div style="padding:3px;"> <?php echo nl2br("$data[cust_exp]"); ?> </div>
     </div>

    <div id="techSumBox">
      <div class="titleText boxTitle"> Technical Summary </div>
      <div style="padding-top:2px;"> <?php echo nl2br("$data[summary]"); ?> </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Can someone please tell me why this is failing in firefox/chrome?

thanks.

Comment: because only certain elements can have 'focus', and a `div` is not one of them.

Comment: hmm how come it appears to be work in IE?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/focus/  read the api

Comment: It is not true that div cannot have focus.  In IE div can have focus.  Try again.